# custom module local > etc > config file not working magento

Tags: configuration

I am new to magento development.Routes end with 404 page

[image]

[image]

It end with 404 page not found but if I move xml tags for routes to Adidas_CasualShoes.xml routes start working. it look like my local module configuration file is not working.

How I can debug and resolve this issue.

Comment: What URL are you trying to use, and what does your controller class look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following in your `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Adidas_CasualShoes>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Adidas_CasualShoes>
    </modules>
```

The module delcaration needs to match the same in your `app/etc/modules/Adidas_CasualShoes.xml`